# Python , передача атрибутов одного класса другому

Tags: python, tkinter

Как передать атрибут `tree` класса `Main()` в функцию `add_item()` класса `DB()`?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import StringVar

class Main(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_main()

def init_main(self):

    toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fil=tk.Y)

    self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='add.png')
    btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar,  text='Добавить', command = self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd = 0,
                                compound = tk.TOP, image = self.add_img)
    btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, column=('ID','description','costs','total'), height=15 , show='headings')

    self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('description', width=300, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('total',width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    self.tree.heading('ID', text='№')
    self.tree.heading('description', text='Описание')
    self.tree.heading('costs', text='Доход/Расход')
    self.tree.heading('total',text='Итог')

    self.tree.pack()


def open_dialog(self):
    Child()



class Child(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_child()

def init_child(self):
    BD().create()

    self.title('Доходы/Расходы')
    self.geometry('400x220+400+300')

    label_description = tk.Label(self, text='Описание: ')
    label_description.place(x=50, y=50)
    label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Доходы/Расходы: ')
    label_select.place(x=50, y=80)
    label_sum = tk.Label(self, text='Сумма: ')
    label_sum.place(x=50, y=110)


    self.description = StringVar()
    self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.description)
    self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)

    self.money = StringVar()
    self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.money)
    self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

    self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
    self.combobox.current(0)
    self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

    btn_add = tk.Button(
        self,
        text='Добавить',
        command=lambda: BD().add_item(
            self.description,
            self.combobox,
            self.money
        )
    )
    btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
    btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

    btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
    btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
    btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


    self.grab_set()
    self.focus_set()



class BD:
def create(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                          description text,
                                                          costs text,
                                                          total real)""")
    conn.commit()


def add_item(self, entry_description, combobox, entry_money):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor= conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                  (entry_description.get(), combobox.get(), entry_money.get()))
    conn.commit()

    entry_description.set('')
    entry_money.set('')
```

Comment: Оъясните понятнее, что хотите сделать.

Comment: @Эникейщик , при нажатии кнопки  'Добавить' мне нужно выполнить функцию add_item(), в ходе которой данные из полей ввода сохранятся в базу данных , с этим проблем нет, а затем вывести в главном окне эти полученные данные , но для этого мне нужно передать классу "DB" аттрибут класса Main()   self.tree . Я не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import StringVar

class Main(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_main()

def init_main(self):

    toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fil=tk.Y)

    self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='add.png')
    btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar,  text='Добавить', command = self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd = 0,
                                compound = tk.TOP, image = self.add_img)
    btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, column=('ID','description','costs','total'), height=15 , show='headings')

    self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('description', width=300, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('total',width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    self.tree.heading('ID', text='№')
    self.tree.heading('description', text='Описание')
    self.tree.heading('costs', text='Доход/Расход')
    self.tree.heading('total',text='Итог')

    self.tree.pack()


def open_dialog(self):
    Child()



class Child(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_child()

def init_child(self):
    BD().create()

    self.title('Доходы/Расходы')
    self.geometry('400x220+400+300')

    label_description = tk.Label(self, text='Описание: ')
    label_description.place(x=50, y=50)
    label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Доходы/Расходы: ')
    label_select.place(x=50, y=80)
    label_sum = tk.Label(self, text='Сумма: ')
    label_sum.place(x=50, y=110)


    self.description = StringVar()
    self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.description)
    self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)

    self.money = StringVar()
    self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.money)
    self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

    self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
    self.combobox.current(0)
    self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

    btn_add = tk.Button(
        self,
        text='Добавить',
        command=lambda: BD().add_item(
            self.description,
            self.combobox,
            self.money,
            self.tree
        )
    )
    btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
    btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

    btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
    btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
    btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


    self.grab_set()
    self.focus_set()



class BD:
def create(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                          description text,
                                                          costs text,
                                                          total real)""")
    conn.commit()


def add_item(self, entry_description, combobox, entry_money, three):
    # тут можете использовать полученную переменную three
    conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor= conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                  (entry_description.get(), combobox.get(), entry_money.get()))
    conn.commit()

    entry_description.set('')
    entry_money.set('')
```

Comment: Даже при текущей непонятной формулировке вопроса, ваш ответ вообще не о том. Даже не принимая во внимание то, что ответ из одного кода без объяснений сам по себе плох.

Comment: @Эникейщик уверены в своих словах? я за сегодня уже третий или четвертый раз отвечаю этому пользователю, и эту программу я вижу уже не впервые, первый его вопрос был по похожему сформулирован, я там всё описал и изменил код. Теперь опять тот же вопрос, только с другой переменной и с непонятным описанием. А вы мне говорите мой ответ не о том.. да ну?

Comment: В каком именно месте у вас передается аттрибут ``tree`` класса Main  в функцию add_item (что бы это ни означало)?

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk ,спасибо конечно же за неоднократную помощь, но в данному случае аттрибут self.tree нужно же еще передать и классу Child()?